# Is it possible to pass MySQL variable to shell command within `\!`

Tags: mysql

Suppose that I have a MySQL variable that I want to be printed out to the screen with some accompanying text. I could do that like this:

```
set @some_var := 1024;
select @some_var "My accompanying text";
```

But is it possible to use that variable within `system` or `\!` command somehow, for instance:

```
set @some_var := 1024;
\! echo "My accompanying text:" @some_var
```

Comment: Are you running the "mysql" commandline tool?  Does your shell understand "echo"?

Comment: @RickJames Yes to both questions. So the output for the last line is `My accompanying text: @some_var` instead of `My accompanying text: 1024`

Comment: How about `SELECT CONCAT("My accompanying text: ", @some_var);`

Comment: @RickJames thank you, it's nearly what I need when an empty string is added as a column alias: `SELECT CONCAT("My accompanying text: ", @some_var) "";`. The problem is that it combines badly with the output in table format (`-t`, `--table`).